# ember-data fixture data "Cannot read property 'promise' of undefined"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is driving me nuts.  I'm more or less following the guide video from http://emberjs.com/guides/, but providing my own data sets for fixture data.  However, no matter what I try I end up with the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'promise' of undefined ember-data.js:240

JS:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'

});

App.UnauthedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.CurrentUser.find();
    }
});

App.CurrentUser = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    session: DS.attr('string')
});

App.CurrentUser.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        username: "gamerbob",
        email: "bob@gamer.com",
        session: "ABC123"
    }
];
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="unauthed">
    Resusult:
    {{#each model}}
        {{username}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

If I remove App.CurrentUser.find() from the route's model hook, there is no error, but that also defeats the purpose.  What's going on here?  Am I doing something wrong, or is this ember-data instability?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the `DS.FixtureAdapter` : `App.CurrentUser.find()` returns an empty array. I'm trying to take a look.

Comment: It seems that it is related to ember-data. Using an older build resolved the problem for me. See: http://builds.emberjs.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of ember-data you are using requires one of the latest build of ember. This is related to RSVP.js that has been upgraded to version 2.0 inside ember.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/cf4d50dd745c8d31a69fe5ad2aea78a92bbbde2a#packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/deferred.js

Comment: Spot on.  Updating to ember-latest resolved the issue.  I was using RC3, which isn't even a week old, so I didn't suspect that.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me which versions of Ember and Ember data are compatible? I have consistantly gotten this error with all versions of Ember and Ember data. It's making me like Backbone even more :)

Comment: If you use the latest (master) version of the libraries you don't get that error.

Comment: Latest builds of both ember and ember-data can be found at http://builds.emberjs.com/